# create attribute option at product import time in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, importexport, avs-fastsimpleimport

I want to create attribute option value at product import time. i used some link but i have no luck with this.

[Magento2 - programmatically add product attribute options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103934/magento2-programmatically-add-product-attribute-options)

https://dev98.de/2016/12/21/how-to-create-attribute-options-in-magento2/

https://webkul.com/blog/programmatically-add-options-attribute-magento2/

Please expert any idea where is my mistake?