# Magento 2 - Create product attribute programmatically

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, install-script

I have create product attribute of type select `select` with below configurations:

```
$setup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'attribute_code', [
            'attribute_model' => NULL,
            'backend' => '',
            'type' => 'int',
            'table' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'input' => 'select',
            'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
            'frontend_class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => '1',
            'default' => 0,
            'unique' => '0',
            'note' => '',
            'input_renderer' => NULL,
            'global' => '1',
            'visible' => '1',
            'searchable' => '0',
            'filterable' => '1',
            'comparable' => '1',
            'visible_on_front' => '1',
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => '0',
            'is_used_for_price_rules' => '1',
            'filterable_in_search' => '1',
            'used_in_product_listing' => '0',
            'used_for_sort_by' => '0',
            'is_configurable' => '1',
            'position' => '1',
            'wysiwyg_enabled' => '0',
            'used_for_promo_rules' => '1',
            'option' =>
                array(
                    'values' => $options,
                ),
            ]
        );
```

How to set default value of this custom attribute?

Comment: Try this => default' => '1',

Comment: How to mention option value which needs to be set as default?

Answer (score 3):

Use below code in:
`Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php` or     `Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeData.php`

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
       $eavSetup->addAttribute(
               \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
           'international',
           [
               'group' => 'General',
               'type' => 'int',
               'label' => 'International',
               'backend' => '',
               'input' => 'select',
               'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
               'source' => 'Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\YesNo',
               'required' => true,
               'sort_order' => 15,
               'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
               'used_in_product_listing' => false,
               'visible_on_front' => false,
       ]
   );

   $setup->endSetup();
```

Source file mentioned above so by defaulty value will be set

```
class YesNo extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    protected $_options;

    /**
     * getAllOptions
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if ($this->_options === null) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['value' => '0', 'label' => __('No')],
                ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Yes')]
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
    final public function toOptionArray()
    {
       return array(
        array('value' => '0', 'label' => __('No')),
        array('value' => '1', 'label' => __('Yes'))
    );
   }
}
```

Comment: can we create without installer?

Comment: If we need programmatically need to have installer scripts.

Comment: can we not create with injecting classes? in controller

Comment: I think we can create, I have not done but it may involves lot of efforts and may have obstacles when compared to setup scripts.

Comment: what "sort_order" does here?

Answer (score 1):

**Follow the Below Steps:-**

Create registration.php in your module

```
<?php
/**
 * Register your module
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_Demo',
    __DIR__
);
```

Create etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Demo" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

Create Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Creating Product attribute
 */

namespace Test\Demo\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


/**
 * Class InstallData
 * @package Test\Demo\Setup
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'test_demo',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Test Demo TextBox',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 3,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Run :-  `php bin/magento setup:upg` 
Done!!

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, Frist You Have to Create vendor/module/**registration.php** file

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, '<vendor>_<module>', __DIR__);
```

Create vendor/module/etc/**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="<vendor>_<module>" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

Create vendor/module/Setup/**InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
        /**
        * EAV setup factory
        *
        * @var EavSetupFactory
        */
        private $eavSetupFactory;

        /**
        * Init
        *
        * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
        */
        public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
        {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        }

        /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
        */
        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
        /* @var EavSetup $eavSetup /
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
        * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
        */
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'call_for_price_active');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'text_demo',
        [

        'type' => 'varchar',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Text Demo',
        'input' => 'boolean',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => 0,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false
        ]
        );
        }
}
```

Comment: Why remove an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.3.3 You can take new approach to add new attributes. Here is my answer to somehow simillar question:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/294521/59161

Answer (score 0):

There are four major steps to create custom product attributes programmatically:

1: Create the Setup File InstallData.php

```
    <?php
namespace Company\Mymodule\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
 private $eavSetupFactory;

 public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
 {
 $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
 }
 
}
```

2: Define the install() Method

3: Create Product Attribute

4: Upgrade

For more details, visit this blog:

[Magento 2 Add Product Attribute Programmatically](https://www.fmeextensions.com/blog/magento-2-add-product-attribute-programmatically/)