# How to add new Option to drop down attributes magento2?

Tags: attributes, dropdown-attribute, attribute-options, option

How to add an new option to product dropdown attribute? If the option already exist it has to skip adding else add option with new value.

I followed the below link 
[How Magento2 add attribute option programmatically (not in setup)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95124/how-magento2-add-attribute-option-programmatically-not-in-setup) where it is creating the option but inserting duplicate if already the option is present.

And can we get the option id after insert is success?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following way:

```
protected $eavAttributeFactory;
protected $attributeOptionManagement;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AttributeFactory $eavAttributeFactory,
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface $attributeOptionManagement
) {

    $this->eavAttributeFactory = $eavAttributeFactory;
    $this->attributeOptionManagement = $attributeOptionManagement;
}
```

And then

```
$magentoAttribute = $this->eavAttributeFactory->create()->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'test_attribute');

$attributeCode = $magentoAttribute->getAttributeCode();
$magentoAttributeOptions = $this->attributeOptionManagement->getItems(
    'catalog_product',
    $attributeCode
);
$attributeOptions = ['Test2', 'Test3'];
$existingMagentoAttributeOptions = [];
$newOptions = [];
$counter = 0;
foreach($magentoAttributeOptions as $option) {
    if (!$option->getValue()) {
        continue;
    }
    if($option->getLabel() instanceof \Magento\Framework\Phrase) {
        $label = $option->getText();
    } else {
        $label = $option->getLabel();
    }

    if($label == '') {
        continue;
    }

    $existingMagentoAttributeOptions[] = $label;
    $newOptions['value'][$option->getValue()] = [$label, $label];
    $counter++;
}

foreach ($attributeOptions as $option) {
    if($option == '') {
        continue;
    }

    if(!in_array($option, $existingMagentoAttributeOptions)) {
        $newOptions['value']['option_'.$counter] = [$option, $option];
    }

    $counter++;
}

if(count($newOptions)) {
    $magentoAttribute->setOption($newOptions)->save();
}
```

Comment: Hi, this code works Perfectly but can we get the option id inserted once the attribute option is saved.

Comment: And is there any code to delete the attribute option?

Comment: @sohail, similar issue I am facing here, can u update me pls, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258787/create-update-attribute-option-custom-api-issue

Comment: Hi,Thanks you saved my day. But I have two stores, the value is updating only in first store

Answer (score 0):

And if we wants to update existing attribute options also insert the new one?

I have a dropdown attribute with in "Admin" value a code and in "Default Store View" a value.

If I found an existing attribute I must update the Default Store View.

Thanks!