# Magento 2, how to add `attribute` and `custom option` of configuration product into cart?

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2, addtocart, rest-api

Using `Magento 2.2`, `API`, `Configurable Product`. I had read the [Similar Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95124/how-magento2-add-attribute-option-programmatically-not-in-setup) for add **attributes** with **custom option** but it cannot help me to understand. I need to create new ***Web Service*** for **Add Product To Cart** look like image below. Please help to explain me.

> **Add Configuration Product To Cart on Web Front End**
>   [image]

Comment: Hello bong, have you find the solution ?

Comment: Hi, I'm not yet.

Comment: Okay here is a way.

Comment: First you need to fetch configurable products attribute option using GET method

Comment: Show me please.

Comment: `http://<magento.host>/rest/V1/configurable-products/<YOUR configurable product SKU>/options/all `

USE GET method in postman and admin token

Comment: Okay, I got this:
`[
    {
        "id": 176,
        "attribute_id": "141",
        "label": "Size",
        "position": 0,
        "values": [
            {
                "value_index": 5
            },
            {
                "value_index": 6
            }
        ],
        "product_id": 962
    }
]`

Comment: Yeah okay now we need to pass this values in POST with Add to cart API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80211/discussion-between-bong-channarith-and-aditya-shah).